# Can we create resource after lambda is created in serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

Am trying to create resource after my lambda is deployed so am using **DependsOn** attribute but I am getting an error stating

```
The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [defineAuthChallenge] in the Resources block of the template
```

I knew my syntax is wrong I have tried different thing but it's not working attaching my code snippet below

```
functions:
  defineAuthChallenge:
    handler: trigger/defineAuthChallenge.handler
    timeout: ${self:custom.service.commonUserTimeout}
    iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - cognito-idp:AdminAddUserToGroup
        - cognito-idp:AdminUpdateUserAttributes
        - cognito-idp:AdminListGroupsForUser
      Resource:
      - '${self:custom.infra.AdminPoolARN}'
      - '${self:custom.infra.ServiceProviderPoolARN}'
      - '${self:custom.infra.OrganizationPoolARN}'
    - Effect : Allow
      Action:
        - 'secretsmanager:GetSecretValue'
      Resource:
        - "arn:aws:secretsmanager:${opt:region}:${self:custom.service.accountId}:secret:aggregationRDSSecreat*"
        - "${self:custom.infra.documentsRsaPrivateSecretKeyARN}"

resources: # CloudFormation template syntax
  Resources:
    DefineLambdaInvokePermission:
      DependsOn: defineAuthChallenge
      Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
      Properties:
        Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        FunctionName: !Sub "arn:aws:lambda:${opt:region}:${self:custom.service.accountId}:function:${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-${self:custom.cognitoStackConfig.Parameters.DefineAuthLambdaName}"
        Principal: "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"
        SourceArn: !Sub "arn:aws:cognito-idp:${opt:region}:${self:custom.service.accountId}:userpool/*"
```

So basically if I try to deploy without `DependsOn` the deployment fails as there is no lambda exists, so all am trying to do is to deploy the lambda first and then create the resource, how can I achieve this, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The name of the Lambda function in your serverless template is `defineAuthChallenge` but Serverless auto-generates an AWS resource name from that which is `DefineAuthChallengeLambdaFunction`.

So, any resource that depends on the function should indicate:

```
DependsOn: DefineAuthChallengeLambdaFunction
```

More generally, Serverless capitalizes the first letter of the Lambda function name and adds a `LambdaFunction` suffix.

Comment: Can you check this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76811205/aws-cognito-custom-challenge-with-resend-code