# AWS Cognito: Custom Challenge with Resend code

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have implemented custom MFA with email verification code, its working fine as expected, but now the problem here is i want to implement Resend code button on front end side, when user clicks that i need to generate a new code and that code should be the active one, How can i achieve it? Can we trigger createAuthChallenge directly? As far as i have seen it's not possible

I have tried one approach, which is sending some reserved keyword, based on it will generate a new code and send it to the user, i can get that reserved code in verifyAuthChallenge, how can i pass that to createAuthChallenge? i tried setting in session array in verifyAuthChallenge, but sessions are not available in verify Auth Challenge request object, hence am struck am updating my code below, any help would be appreciated

**CreateAuthChallenge**

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  log.info("event: ", event);
  let verificationCode = "";
  //Only called once after SRP_A and PASSWORD_VERIFIER challenges. Hence session.length == 2
  if (event.request.session.length === 2) {
    verificationCode = await buildCodeAndSendEmail(event);
  } else {
    log.info("Inside else part");
    //if the user makes a mistake, we utilize the verification code from the previous session so that the user can retry.
    const previousChallenge = event.request.session.slice(-1)[0];
    verificationCode = previousChallenge.challengeMetadata;
    if (verificationCode === "Dummyval") {
      verificationCode = await buildCodeAndSendEmail(event);
    }
  }

  //add to privateChallengeParameters. This will be used by verify auth lambda.
  log.info({ verificationCode }, "verficiation code");
  event.response.privateChallengeParameters = {
    verificationCode: verificationCode,
  };

  //add it to session, so its available during the next invocation.
  event.response.challengeMetadata = verificationCode;

  return event;
```

**VerifyAuthChallenge**

```
exports.handler = asyncHandler((event) => {
  log.info("event: ", event);
  let expectedAnswer =
    event.request.privateChallengeParameters["verificationCode"];
  let timePeriod = expectedAnswer.substring(6, expectedAnswer.length);
  console.log({ timePeriod }, "Time period");
  expectedAnswer = expectedAnswer.substring(0, 6);
  const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  const diff = currentTime - timePeriod;
  const seconds = Math.floor((diff / 1000) % 60);
  const minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
  event.response.answerCorrect = false;
  log.info(expectedAnswer, seconds, minutes, "expectedAnswer seconds minutes");
  if (event.request.challengeAnswer === expectedAnswer && minutes <= process.env.otpTimeLimit ) {
    event.response.answerCorrect = true;
  }

  //DummyVal is a reserved keyword which ill send from frontend based on this am planning to generate new code 
  if(event.request.challengeAnswer === 'Dummyval') {
    // event.request.session[event.request.session.length-1].challengeMetadata = event.request.challengeAnswer;
  }

  log.info({ event }, "return event");

  return event;
});
```

Please note i need to generate a new code only if the user clicks that resend button, not on all the cases